# Azure not forwarding port, firewall disabled

Tags: firewall, azure, port-forwarding

### Context

I have an Azure server running a service on port 8000.

[image: app listening]

This works on localhost:8000.

I have Azure rules to forward port 8000:

[image]

And my firewall is disabled:

[image]

---

### Question

I'm serving HTML files over Node.js. They work locally, and the server reports no errors, but I receive an

> ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE

in chrome. I have tried to run other services, java API's serving json, but nothing works. Other ports, like 8010 or 80 are not functioning eighter.

What can I possibly do to make this port function and enable my webserver?

**More advanced azure rule image:**

[image]

Comment: localhost is just that, local, it's the loopback. It isn't available externally to external clients. What does BrowserSync show for External?

Comment: @Walter-MSFT Hi Walter, I tried to solve it but the issue you thought would help didn't change anything. It already worked if I ran the same setup in a localhost on my PC and connected from another pc. I started another instance of Ubuntu, tried the same, no luck aside from port 80 and 443. Now I build a gateway server, run that on port 80, and let that server forward requests to internal ports. I've got my setup working, and maybe I'm even happier with this approach. Thank you though!

Comment: @Walter-MSFT Port 80 worked on the old setup as well I guess, I didn't realise you need superuser access to open port 80. It would've worked if I set my node app to port 80 instead of 8000, but then my microservices on the same server on different ports would not work anyways.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to your description, it seems that your service only is listening on `127.0.0.1`, so, you only could access the service inside your VM. You could check use following command.

`netstat -ant|findstr 8000`.

Please ensure your service is listening on `0.0.0.0.` or VM's private IP like `10.0.0.4`.  Maybe you need modify your service configuration.

Comment: In order to better solve this problem, could you show the result `netstat -ant|findstr 8000`?